# Httpwebrequest make request with cookies deny/disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

Hello i making a simple httpwebrequest but the response that i get is sow me the same page like if i set cookie to Deny manually in (F12).any one know  how to fix it
becuse it seems like my httpwebrequest  have cookies=Deny setting

I just want to send HttpWebRequest  then to read the html page from HttpWebResponse,but the html page that i get from HttpWebResponse  is like if i set cookie to Deny manually in (F12)browser.i did that for check and get the same page

This my code

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using HtmlAgilityPack;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace BbvaBank
    {
        static class bBank
        {
            static CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer();



    static string loginPostUrl = "https://www.bbvanetcash.com/local_kyop/KYOPSolicitarCredenciales.html";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPostUrl);
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    //Get the response from the server and save the cookies from the first request..

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
Stream streamResponseLogin = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamReadLogin = new StreamReader(streamResponseLogin);
LoginInfo = streamReadLogin.ReadToEnd();//here i see the page

    }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please reword your question? It's really hard to understand  what you're asking... Tell us clearly what you want and what you get.

Comment: I just want to send HttpWebRequest  then to read the html page from HttpWebResponse,but the html page that i get from HttpWebResponse  is like if i set cookie to Deny manually in (F12)browser.i did that for check and get the same page

Comment: If you're saying you want cookies to controle rights, be careful about that. Cookies can be forged and modified. At least do some form of data encryption (still not a great way to go, but better) on the cookies

Comment: @VovaPotapov, the setting in the browser only affects the browser, not your code. The cookies aren't shared between your program and the browser.

Comment: I know :).... but again when i get the html page from HttpWebResponse   i see only one label, but in browser all fine,then i press F12 and disable the cookies(to check) and then in the browser i get the same page with one label and i thinking that my(code) HttpWebRequest is some how have cookies=deny settings

Comment: Just go to the link  and press f12 to set the cookies to deny and you will see  the page that i get in code  https://www.bbvanetcash.com/local_kyop/KYOPSolicitarCredenciales.html